# Google books API searching by ISBN

Tags: java, isbn, google-books-api

I am trying to figure out how to search for a book by ISBN using the Google Books API. I need to write a program that searches for an ISBN then prints out the title, author, and edition. I tried using `List volumesList = books.volumes.list("");` but that did not allow me to search by ISBN and I did not see a way to get the information I needed(when an ISBN was placed in it had no results) . What I have right now is:

```
    JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();     
    final Books books = new Books(new NetHttpTransport(), jsonFactory);
    List volumesList = books.volumes.list("9780262140874");

    volumesList.setMaxResults((long) 2);

    volumesList.setFilter("ebooks");
    try
    {
        Volumes volumes = volumesList.execute();
        for (Volume volume : volumes.getItems()) 
        {
            VolumeVolumeInfo volumeInfomation = volume.getVolumeInfo();
            System.out.println("Title: " + volumeInfomation.getTitle());
            System.out.println("Id: " + volume.getId());
            System.out.println("Authors: " + volumeInfomation.getAuthors());
            System.out.println("date published: " + volumeInfomation.getPublishedDate());
            System.out.println();
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("didnt wrork "+ex.toString());
    }
```

If anyone has any suggestions about how to make this more efficient let me know.
New Code:

```
    String titleBook="";

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////
    try
    {                               
        BooksService booksService = new BooksService("UAH");
        String isbn = "9780262140874";
        URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com/books/feeds/volumes/?q=ISBN%3C" + isbn + "%3E");
        VolumeQuery volumeQuery = new VolumeQuery(url);
        VolumeFeed volumeFeed = booksService.query(volumeQuery, VolumeFeed.class);
        VolumeEntry bookInfo=volumeFeed.getEntries().get(0);

        System.out.println("Title: " + bookInfo.getTitles().get(0));
        System.out.println("Id: " + bookInfo.getId());
        System.out.println("Authors: " + bookInfo.getAuthors());
        System.out.println("Version: " + bookInfo.getVersionId());
        System.out.println("Description: "+bookInfo.getDescriptions()+"\n");
        titleBook= bookInfo.getTitles().get(0).toString();
        titleBook=(String) titleBook.subSequence(titleBook.indexOf("="), titleBook.length()-1);
    }catch(Exception ex){System.out.println(ex.getMessage());}
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////
    JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();     
    final Books books = new Books(new NetHttpTransport(), jsonFactory);
    List volumesList = books.volumes.list(titleBook);   
    try
    {
        Volumes volumes = volumesList.execute();
        Volume bookInfomation= volumes.getItems().get(0);

        VolumeVolumeInfo volumeInfomation = bookInfomation.getVolumeInfo();
        System.out.println("Title: " + volumeInfomation.getTitle());
        System.out.println("Id: " + bookInfomation.getId());
        System.out.println("Authors: " + volumeInfomation.getAuthors());
        System.out.println("date published: " + volumeInfomation.getPublishedDate());
        System.out.println();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("didnt wrork "+ex.toString());
    }
```

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Are you using the [deprecated data API](http://code.google.com/apis/books/docs/gdata/developers_guide_java.html)?

With [Books API v1](http://code.google.com/apis/books/docs/v1/using.html) (from Labs) you could use the query

```
https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:<your_isbn_here>
```

for example

https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:0735619670

to query a book by its ISBN.

You may want to look at Googles example code: [BooksSample.java](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/books-cmdline-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/books/cmdline/BooksSample.java?repo=samples)

Comment: The way you suggested is for HTML not java. The way BooksSample does it is the same as I have above and does not allow for search by ISBN.List volumesList = books.volumes.list(query) is the code they used also query is a string.

Comment: The query uses a HTTP GET request and receives the response in JSON format, which is language-independent and commonly used in Java. There is no HTML involved.

Comment: please note: 
https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn0735619670 return "totalItems": 78

colon fwd! can't belive that's not documented somewhere (atleast i didn't find it)

https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn<0735619670> returns "totalItems": 511

but https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:0735619670 does a exact search and returns "totalItems": 1.

Colon FWD! Can't belive that's not documented somewhere (atleast i didn't find it)

Comment: @masi Thank you. I changed the query string accordingly.

Comment: @masi: Thanks! Note that it is also case-sensitive, so `q=ISBN:9780321694690` will return the long list, while `q=isbn:9780321694690` will return the specific match.

Comment: @Chris Thanks a lot. I was trying to implement a code which searches Google books, but I was a bit worried about the application level quota (1000 per day). Using your URL directly in a GET request, I am now able to receive data without even using a key, which I guess overcomes the quota trouble.

Answer (score 4):

Can't you try like this as said in the developers guide [developer guide](http://code.google.com/apis/books/docs/gdata/developers_guide_java.html) if I did understand your task. You can do like this :

```
BooksService booksService = new BooksService("myCompany-myApp-1");
myService.setUserCredentials("user@domain.com", "secretPassword");

String isbn = "9780552152679";
URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com/books/feeds/volumes/?q=ISBN%3C" + isbn + "%3E");
VolumeQuery volumeQuery = new VolumeQuery(url);
VolumeFeed volumeFeed = booksService.query(volumeQuery, VolumeFeed.class);

// using an ISBN in query gives only one entry in VolumeFeed
List<VolumeEntry> volumeEntries = volumeFeed.getEntries();
VolumeEntry entry = volumeEntries.get(0);
```

Now using the [VolumeEntry](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/javadoc/com/google/gdata/data/books/VolumeEntry.html) api look for your desired getXXXX() and use it in your code.I hope it will help you to solve your problem.

Comment: Your answer worked pretty well It got me the correct title of the book with the corresponding ISBN. However when even I called bookInfo.getAuthors() it returned a blank list. When printed it looked like the following "Authors: []"

Comment: can do  bookInfo.getCreators() ? It should return a list of creators as instances of Creator. Then you can get the authors. May be it will work as I did not try it. Have a try.

Comment: I was able to get it working with the new code above. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I just tried the getCreatos and it cut my code in half thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure I get where the BooksService type is coming from

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("form").submit(
  function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var isbn = $('#ISBN').val();
    var isbn_without_hyphens = isbn.replace(/-/g, "");
    var googleAPI = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=" + isbn_without_hyphens;
    $.getJSON(googleAPI, function(response) {
      if (typeof response.items === "undefined") {
        alert("No books match that ISBN.")
      } else {
        $("#title").html(response.items[0].volumeInfo.title);
        $("#author").html(response.items[0].volumeInfo.authors[0]);
        $("#publishedDate").html(response.items[0].volumeInfo.publishedDate);
      }
    });
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <strong>Enter ISBN:</strong> <input type="text" id="ISBN" value="9781407170671">
  <input type="submit" id="submit">
</form>
Title: <span id="title"></span>
<br> Author: <span id="author"></span>
<br> Publication date: <span id="publishedDate"></span>
```